# My wordpress Navigation menu is not showing in the responsive window

Tags: wordpress

Hi Please check out [wwww.eleasee.com](http://eleasee.com). The Navigation menu is responsive, how ever in smaller screens when we wish to expand the menu nothing shows up. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to add a extra mobile menu here? [eleasee.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php](http://eleasee.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php)